# JS: axios POST with large nested object and form-data

Tags: javascript, post, axios, form-data

I am to `post` an Axios request because using `get` results in a 414 error.
Here's the object:

```js
rows= {
  0 : {
    "name":"Thor",
    "status":"active",
    "email":"somuchlightning@kaboom.io",
  },
  1 : {
    "name":"Mesa",
    "status":"active",
    "email":"big-mesa@tundra.com",
  },
  2 : {
    "name":"Jesper",
    "status":"stdby",
    "email":"jes@slap.net,
  },
}
```

This is just a sample of the object's format. There is 400+ elements in the real one, thus `post` instead of `get`. I am having trouble properly building the form-data on this one. Here's what I have:

```js
let data = new FormData();
Object.keys(rows).forEach(key => data.append(key, rows[key]));  //  <--- this doesn't do
data.set('target', target);  //  <---- this comes through just fine

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'byGrabthorsHammer.php',
  data: data,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.error) {
    console.log('failed to send list to target');
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    console.log('response: ');
    console.log(response);
  }        
});
```

What comes through is just `[Object][Object]' when i`var_dump($_POST);`.  This is not what I want. How could I rewrite this properly so I get the data to the other side (like GET...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yow bro, `POST` Are for inserting new stuff, instead of doing a post you need a patch 
axios.patch it is basically the same. And it won’t fix your issue.
To fix the issue you need to set the `Content-Type` to application/json, then on yow

```
axios.post(url, data: JSON.stringify(bigObject))
   .then(Rea=>Rea)
```

Comment: m'okay.  didn't even consider this... if you have time, WHY does this work and not the other?

Comment: the headers if you want it to work like on your code, you need to change the header like o. postman

Answer (score 1):

You could try stringifying the data. JSON.stringify(data)